# time series decomposition seasonal_decompose

Tags: time-series, decomposition

I have two time series and I did a decomposition for both in python using

seasonal_decompose  from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal using freq = 7. I'm thinking they have weekly seasonality.
[image]

This one shows weekly seasonality as I think.

[image]

The second one I also used same parameter,but somehow there is jitter in the seasonal component. What do you think what might cause this behavior?
Thanks.

Comment: What do the two original datasets represent?

Comment: The first one is retail sales so there is apparent holiday effect. Another one is just a  general website traffic time series and sometimes some random special events might trigger the increase of the traffic.

Comment: Based on this, you would probably see a weekly trend (assuming these are daily sales) in both datasets.  In retail, we should intuitively expect sales to increase over the weekend when more people are shopping/not working.  The hiccup you see in the weekly trend could be interpreted if we have more information.  For example, if this website is "religious" in nature, maybe people are more interested in visiting it around Sunday mass (the big spike) and Wednesday gatherings (the little spike).  It is really tough to know without further information.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "jitter in the seasonal component" and how that is reflected in the second plot?

Comment: Maybe I should use hiccup.I refer to the small peak following the big peak in the seasonal plot.